# How to manage and structure pages and links in server root folder (PHP)

Tags: php, xampp, include-path, document-root

I am not using any framework, just working in XAMPP environment.

Like all i am also having an index file index.php and most importantly i want to add same header to all my pages.

In my index.php page i add my header like

```
<?php include 'html/headers/header.html'; ?>
```

and in my page.php page which is inside info folder in the root folder like c:/xampp/htdocs/website/info

```
<?php include '../html/headers/header.html'; ?>
```

All work fine, but problem arises when the path of images inside heeader remains the same, i.e the image path works good for index.php file but not for page.php file,the reason you know already.

I tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/website/images/logo.png".` Neither it worked nor i want this technique as there can be many images in header plus footer etc.

I am also not wanting to use any framework or cdn storage.

Can this be solved easily. Let me know if i missed anything. Thanx

Comment: @DanFromGermany Just edit the question

Comment: Include the Header in an index.php. There you load different pages like info with an GET[] parameter ?. Is simple, fast and lightweight.

Comment: @Zafta Should i post you some Code, that u understand what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

When I'm coding in PHP I tend to have two variables at the start of each of my PHP files.

```
// Use for file on the server, eg includes
$file_path = "../";

// For files relative to my page path, eg images, links
$link_path = "../../";
```

I change each of these depending on the location of the file.

I then prepend any includes with the `$file_path` and things on the page (eg images, hyperlinks) with `$link_path`.

```
echo '<img src="' . $link_path . 'images/myimage.png" />';
include ($file_path . "html/headers/header.html");
```

That's how I do it anyway...

Set the variables at the top of each new page that you create and them within your page and any includes.

```
// New file
$file_path = "../";
$link_path = "../../";

include($file_path . "html/headers/header.html");
```

Then within your header.html and within the page, you'd go:

```
echo '<img src="' . $link_path . 'website/images/logo.png" />';
```

If you want a link, you'd go:

```
echo '<a href="' . $link_path . 'website/page.html'>My Link</a>';
```

Comment: Images in the header.html File wouldnt be displayed, cause the img src there is given for index.php !

Comment: That's why you would use the `$link_path` for images within your included files.  Making sure that each file has the correct paths.

Comment: Than the index.php is not working ! Two diffrent Link Paths and only 1 File

Comment: @Coulton is it efficient and good to technique to use this always

Comment: @Zafta Good question, probably not, but it is a simple solution to ensure that you're getting your URLs correct

Comment: but hey images are inside in header.html .. how to know what variable is to use ../../ or ../ ?? @Coulton

Comment: Please see the edit I just made, hopefully that makes it a bit more clear?  You need to set your variables based on the location of the file you're creating ($file_path) and the intended URL that it will be accessed from ($link_path)

Answer (score 0):

This is your index.php page

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $dir = 'page/' . $_GET['page']. '.php';
        if(file_exists($dir)) {
            include_once($dir);
        } else {
            include_once('page/404.php');
        }
    } else {
        include_once('page/home.php');
    }
?>
```

You have a Folder Structure like this

- pages
- sections
- index.php

In pages you save home.php, info.php etc.
And in sections you save header.php, footer.php etc.

Than you use the image src form your index.php and you have no problems any more.

Comment: good first cut, but is it always efficient to display entities based on GET variables ??